# Why is my code not implementing the Javascript/JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am not sure what the problem with my code is but I am unable to scroll as my code is meant to do.

I think the Javascript/JQuery is not being read or I am not implementing it properly.

The working example of this code can be found in the answer to this question:

[How to scroll HTML Page all the way down and restart again from top?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60785333/how-to-scroll-html-page-all-the-way-down-and-restart-again-from-top)

I will appreciate any help.

Top HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
<style>
h2 {color:red;}
p {color:blue;}
  #scroll { 
    overflow-y: scroll; width:100%; height:1000px
  }

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="scroll">

  <h2>This is a heading</h2>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<p>This is another paragraph.</p>
...
```

Javascript code at the end of the body tag:

```
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function animatethis(targetElement, speed) {
    var scrollHeight = $(targetElement).get(0).scrollHeight;
    var clientHeight = $(targetElement).get(0).clientHeight;
    $(targetElement).animate({ scrollTop: scrollHeight - clientHeight },
    {
        duration: speed,
        complete: function () {
            targetElement.animate({ scrollTop: 0 },
            {
                duration: speed,
                complete: function () {
                    animatethis(targetElement, speed);
                }
            });
        }
    });
};
animatethis($('#scroll'), 5000);

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: put your scripts in the body below the content

Comment: @ZohirSalak It does'nt work when I put it at the end of body tag as well.

Comment: Add a screenshot of your console.

Comment: It does not show any errors. It is just empty.

Answer (score 1):

Your script tags should be the last elements inside the .

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        your styles
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <your body stuff>
    <script>Here goes your script</script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is so that all your html loads before reading the script.

Comment: Thank you for your help, however, this does not solve the problem

Comment: If you want to quickly check if your javascript is being read, put a console.log('in the javascript or whatever'); at the beginning of your function. If you can see it, then it's a problem within your code, not the javascript not being read.